# When connecting to Snowflake internal stage I am seeing it connect to a different db

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am connecting through newly released Snowflake Kafka connector using standalone mode. The connector is able to connect to my snowflake account successfully but when it looks for creating internal stage, it doesn't use correct database as in config

This is the content of new connector.properties file:

```
name=kafkaSnowNow

connector.class=com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector

tasks.max=8

topics=kafkaSnow1,kafkaSnow2

snowflake.topic2table.map= kafkaSnow1:kafka_db.kafka_schema.kafkaSnow1,kafkaSnow2:kafka_db.kafka_schema.kafkaSnow2

buffer.count.records=100

buffer.flush.time=60

buffer.size.bytes=65536

snowflake.url.name=https://xyz.ap-southeast-2.snowflakecomputing.com:443

snowflake.user.name=xyz_user

snowflake.private.key=

snowflake.database.name=kafka_db

snowflake.schema.name=kafka_schema

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter

value.converter=com.snowflake.kafka.connector.records.SnowflakeJsonConverter
```

When I start connector, the attempt to write records is being made but it looks for below stage.

```
desc stage
identifier(SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_kafkaSnowNow_STAGE_kafka_db.kafka_schema.kafkaSnow1)
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is going to be best raised on the github repo: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-kafka-connector/issues

Comment: Agreed, I am having some troubles getting back in contact with the Snowflake user, but I have pointed them there when they do come back to their original question. @RobinMoffatt thank you kindly for the direction.